# Where to find subscription-manager-migration-data 1.24 for CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7, spacewalk, katello

This is driving me crazy !!!
I'm in the process of migrating around 20-ish CentOS 7 machines from Spacewalk to Katello.
To accomplish this I want to use **katello_bootstrap.py** script to automate it.
That script depends on subscription-manager and subscription-manager-migration which depends on subscription-manager-data.

I was able to find https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1908.u.x86_64 to use as repo, which contains **subscription-manager-migration-1.24.13-4.el7.centos.x86_64**, but not the **-data** package.

Please help me !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 4 month old post, but I'm running into the same thing trying to get this package installed, while trying to migrate to satellite.

Any chance you found a solution?